# Adding bitmap to email from excel VBA

Tags: vba, email

All,

I am trying to generate an email from an Excel button that has a text and picture in the body.  I am almost there thanks to another thread on this site.

The issue I am having is that the picture is not pasting in the correct place.

Here is the code I am using (I will explain the problem after):

```
Set snapshot = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set snapshot = ssSheet.Range("A2:J47").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
snapshot.Copy
Set snapshot = Nothing

strBody = "All," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Attached is the """ & [projectname] & _
    """ project playbook for week of " & [StartDate] & " for your review." &     vbCrLf & _
    "Please advise if additional clarification or information is required." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
    "For full Playbook details, please click on the below link or reference the attached PDF file." & vbCrLf & _
    "https://project.wyn.com/whg/102390/Status%20Reports/Forms/All.aspx" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

pos = InStr(strBody, "file")
MsgBox pos

'Create mail item and view
Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
'Get its Word editor
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Set wordDoc = MItem.GetInspector.WordEditor

With MItem
    .To = strTo
    .Subject = strSubj
    .CC = strCC
    .Attachments.Add (pdfFileName)
    .Body = strBody
    wordDoc.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
    wordDoc.Application.Selection.End = wordDoc.Application.Selection.Start
    wordDoc.Application.Selection.PasteSpecial , , , wdInLine, wdpastedbitmap
    .Display
End With
```

What is happening is that the picture is getting after the first 2 lines of text and covering the 2nd 2 lines.  I also tried setting the position by using InStr function, which is also not working.

I am so close, just need to have the picture pasted below the last line (html link).

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to consider using `.HTMLBody` instead of `.Body`. There you have so much more options to place the picture where you want them to be. And [any given online HTML editor](http://www.quackit.com/html/online-html-editor/) will help you create the necessary HTML-code.

Comment: Thanks Ralph - I have also gone down that road.  In order to do that I need to take the range, save it as a chart, export that as a .jpg image and then use HTML - is that correct?  Was trying to go the above route simply for the ease.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about and at the same time I would not know what the content of your picture / PDF file is that you want to attach to your email (if that's what you are referring to). All I am saying is, that you can control / change the format of an HTML email much better when compared to a normal (text-only) email. BTW: at the moment the above code is merely adding a PDF file and not a picture.